# generic interface within delegate at startup class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, azure-functions

Using .Net6
Azure function
I am trying to refactor out an existing set of logic to return an object of type T vs the current void.
The current solution is first with my attempt below:

**CURRENT**

The current **closed** IHandler code/implementation is

```cs
IHandler.cs
{
    Task HandleAsync(IMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

and in program.cs

```cs
services.AddScoped<Func<MessageType, IHandler>>(sp =>
    dataType =>
    {
        switch (dataType)
        {
            case MessageType.HandleA:
                return sp.GetService<HandleA>();

            case MessageType.HandleB:
                return sp.GetService<HandleB>();
```

Implementation

```cs
public class HandleA: IHandler
{
    public async HandleAsync(IMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    { ... //do work in here
    }
}
```

**PROPOSED ATTEMPT**

The Problem:
What I would like to do is create a handler that returns a generic object but the delegate in program is messing with my head.
Current (not compiling, but can't see way out)

```cs
public interface ISvcMessageHandler<T> : IHandler where T : class
{
    Task<List<T>> ReturnObject(IMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

program.cs
**The issue here is that I have to strongly declare T with a concrete class**

```cs
//obviously T is not known here. 
services.AddScoped<Func<MessageType, ISvcMessageHandler<T>>>(sp =>
    dataType =>
    {
        switch (dataType)
        {
            case MessageType.HandleA:
                return sp.GetService<HandleA<DtoA>>();

            case MessageType.HandleB:
                return sp.GetService<HandleB<DtoB>>();
```

Implementation

```cs
public class HandleA: ISvcMessageHandler<DtoA>
{
    public async Task<List<DtoA>> ReturnObject(IMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ....do work
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not only the registration. How do you want to consume this service? You need to know the type returned by the service at compile time. In `List<?> list = await handle.ReturnObject(messageType, cancellationToken);` what should the type of `list` be?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean @OlivierJacot-Descombes At the implementation and the injection, I state I want HandleA to return DtoA and HandleB to return DtoB .. this would be List<DtoA> ...
Perhaps this is entirely the wrong way to do it.... 
Are you saying the signature should be 
```Task<List<T>> ReturnObject<T>(IMessa... ? ```

Comment: The problem is that at runtime the same call might once return `List<DtoA>` and another time `List<DtoB>`, depending on `dataType`. How do you want to handle this?

Comment: within our function we resolve based on the MessageType passed in as a param. 

current:  `private readonly Func<MessageType, IHandler> _resolver;
     messageHandler = _resolver(MessageType.HandleA); `

I am not sure that would need to change though because the injection has already happened and said if the person wants to handle messageType.HandleA give them this service that returns a List<DtoA>? 
Is this more trouble than its worth? Genuinely curious if this is possible or just not worth the hassle.

Comment: Couldn't you just register `services.AddScoped<Func<MessageType, IHandler>>(...)`? Because every `ISvcMessageHandler<T>` implements `IHandler`. But you still have the problem that you must cast the handler to one of the types ` `ISvcMessageHandler<DtoA>` or ` `ISvcMessageHandler<DtoB>` to be able to call `ReturnObject`.

Comment: Yes, this was my direction of thought as well. Individual scoped services for each. I'll take a look at that direction. Thanks.